# Different ways of exchanging tokens

Tags: tokens, contract-invocation, transfer

I am conducting a study on transaction behaviour and dynamics on the Ethereum blockchain. Currently, I am analysing the token transfers of different user groups. After leveraging Google Big Query and Etherscan to get more insights on that, I noticed that there must be different ways of transferring tokens between addresses. I found these two different examples where tokens are transferred:

- Token transfer by interacting directly with the token contract (sending a transaction to that contract)
  https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf1e3f104ac1edb3008be562f547b0a25f73d7cabccaef02abd15bfd0bf8ce25f
- Token transfer by interacting with a smart contract (not the token contract), which then executes one or several token transfers
  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x002d18916adee8aa0d690e1b9947281d4272abaf870192233ade43399f2dcd4a

Are there any other ways to transfer tokens and what sort of token transfers do the two examples above illustrate?

Thanks!

Comment: Any token transfer has to be done through the token contract, so either you can it directly or through another contract.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks! But why is the token contract not addressed in the transaction in the second link then?

Comment: The token contract should be addressed. Etherscan shows a high level view of the transaction the exact details can be retrieved by tracing a transaction. If you look at the 'Parity Trace' option it will show you calls to other contracts, some of the calls are to the token 0xa821f1..